# Filter excel column by array values using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel column that contains app code followed by a short description of the app (BF00 Account App).  The column is long and there are many apps, I want to filter this column just by app codes.  This is the method I have created but it doesn't seem to be working :/

```
Private Sub FilterAppCodes()
Dim unfilter As Worksheet
Dim FindOutArray() As String
Dim iRow As Double
Dim CodeDef As Variant
Dim AppCodes As Variant
AppCodes = Array("A0A0", "B03B"....)
Dim iTotRecsA As Double
iRow = 2
Set unfilter = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(UN_FILTERED_SHEET)
iTotRecsA = unfilter.Range(ID_NUM & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

'Use a while loop to loop through the first sheet until Id's are blank
While unfilter.Cells(iRow, 1) <> ""

'Load all App codes & description in CodeDef
CodeDef = unfilter.Cells(iRow, 5)
Debug.Print (CodeDef)

    iRow = iRow + 1
Wend
FindOutArray = filter(SourceArray:=CodeDef, _
       Match:=AppCodes, _
       Include:=True, _
       Compare:=vbTextCompare)
    If UBound(FindOutArray) = -1 Then
        Debug.Print ("No, Array doesn't contain this item - " & strText)
    Else
        Debug.Print ("Yes, Array contains this item - " & strText)
    End If
End Sub
```

I load all the column data in the CodeDef variant and I try to compare it with the values in the array. I was wondering if this is right?  I am getting a "Type mismatch" error on the FindOutArray = Filter(SourceArray....part.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: is there some reason you can't use Excel filtering?

Comment: The "match" parameter for Filter doesn't take an array.  "I load all the column data in the CodeDef variant" - you're only loading the *last* one.

Comment: And why is Double used for a row number? And you don't include your declarations and assignments for UN_FILTERED_SHEET and ID_NUM.